# How to make a process run on AWS EC2 even after closing the local machine?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a script that will take around 10-15 hours to complete. I want to run it on EC2 instance and after say 10 hours stop the process forever.

Approaches--

`CRONTAB` -if I make a cronjob for the process . How to ensure it runs only once in lifetime and delete after 10 hour?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to open a [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) session. You can do this by typing `screen` in the bash prompt. Once you have fired in your command, type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd>. This will detach your screen session. However the script that you run will continue to run.

Now, you can disconnect from your SSH session. And once you log back in, you can `resume` your session by typing in `screen -r`. This is assuming that you have only one `detached` session. In case you have more than one, you will have to type in the pid of the session you want to attach back to.

To check the `pid` of the session, you can do:

```
ps aux | grep screen
```

This will list out the currently running screen processes. A sample output is:

```
dhanush          1327   0.0  0.0  2443312     56 s000  S+    3Sep15   0:00.99 screen -r server -p server
dhanush         79037   0.0  0.0  2432784    600 s008  S+    5:03PM   0:00.00 grep screen
```

Here the `pid` for the relevant screen process is `1327`.
The second line belongs to the `grep` command that searched for the keyword `screen` itself.

[tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1) is another alternative for the same.

Comment: How to check the pid of the session ?

Comment: The script will be running in the background even if I close the local machine? and when I come back and check screen -r the script will have completed the processing

Comment: Yes. Even if you turn off your local machine.

Comment: In case you have multiple sessions, `screen -r` will display the pids

Comment: If I disconnect from aws ssh session, the process started using screen also stops. I had to use disown -a to disconnect and close ssh so the process continues to run